# Freezing layers for finetuning

Tags: training, fine-tuning

So i'm planning to fine tune a 7b parameter model for a research project. I understand the different steps of model fine tuning, namely

1. Supervised fine tuning - where we train model on curated examples to impart domain specific knowledge (could be instruction fine tuning as well)
2. DPO/PPO - this step is done for model alignment to human preferences

I understand there is a huggingface library which has built wrappers around these both but I'm trying to get an in depth understanding. So how I see a language model with depth N is that the first N-1 layers are building a representation and last layer is a policy network, i.e. takes the representation and spits out a probability distribution over the tokens. Now my main question, in SFT and DPO/PPO is there any literature which describes the following and provides benchmarks/ablation studies for the following -

1. Doing SFT (no frozen parameters) and only using adapters for DPO/PPO
2. Doing SFT by freezing all layers except the last and followed by DPO/PPO on last layer
3. Doing SFT using adapters/LoRA, merging the weights, followed by adapters for DPO/PPO
4. Doing SFT using adapters/LoRA, merging the weights, followed by DPO/PPO on only last layer
5. Vanilla option, i.e. SFT followed by DPO/PPO no frozen weights.

Any reference for literature or anecdotal evidence would be appreciated.